# How to show there is only one homomorphism between $\mathbb Z_{25}$ and $S_4$?

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

> Show that there is only one homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_{25}$ to $S_4$.

How do i approach this question? If anyone could give me a hint or some guidelines that would be great.

Comment: Only one but the trivial one?

Comment: A homomorphism from ${\mathbb Z}_{25}$ (to anything) is totally determined by the image of 1. As 1 has order 25, its image must have order 1, 5 or 25. Which of these is at all possible in $S_4$?

Comment: @Sigur: No. Only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is a cyclic group and $g\in C$ is a generator for $C$, then any homomorphism $\phi:C\to H$ is determined by the value of $\phi(g)$ (why?). Then to show there is a unique homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/25$ to $S_4$, it suffices to show that there's only one possible value of $\phi(1)$ in $S_4$.(Consider the order of $\phi(1)$.)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\phi$ is such a homomorphism. Then $(\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z})/\ker (\phi)\simeq im(\phi)\le S_4$. By Lagrange, $\ker(\phi)$ has $1$, $5$, or $25$ elements, and
$im(\phi)$ has $1,2,3,4,6,12,24$ elements. On the other hand, $(\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z})/\ker (\phi)$ and $im(\phi)$ must have the same number of elements. That only leaves $\# \, im(\phi)=1$.

Comment: Thanks guys! you guys are aewsome.